# Сохранение фаила в Excel в python

Tags: python, excel

Доброго вечера.

У меня есть вопрос, который я никак не могу решить. Есть папка с картинками, и есть файл эксель в котором есть все названия этих картинок. Например в файле есть название "тумба", а в папке с картинками есть файлы "тумба_1", "тумба_2", "тумба_3" и т.д.. Мне необходимо брать из экселевского файла по очереди названия и искать по маске картинки. После чего записывая их в эксель файл горизонтально:
тумба тумба_1 тумба_2 тумба_3

Я застрял на поиске функцией glob, вот лислинг:

```
 import xlrd
 from glob import glob
 import csv
 import os
 import xlwt

 T = []

 def read_file(location):
   book = xlrd.open_workbook(location)
   sheet = book.sheet_by_index(0)
   os.chdir('C:\photo-magazin\mebel')
   a = 0
   for r in range (1, sheet.nrows):
     name_picture = sheet.cell(r, 0).value
     print(name_picture)
     current_photos = glob(name_picture + '*')
     print(current_photos)
     workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
     worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('date')
     n = len(current_photos)
     a = 0
     for i in current_photos:
        print(a)
        print(i)
        worksheet.write(a, n, i)
        n = n - 1
        workbook.save('example.xls')

 def main():
   read_file('C:\photo-magazin\mebel_photo.xlsx')

 if __name__ == '__main__':
   main()
```

Команда `print(current_photos)` не выводит ничего, хотя переменная `name_picture`, которая идет в качестве маски содержит данные.

Вот пример вывода:

```
 Тумба с раковиной Акватон Венеция 90 черная
 []
 Мебель для ванной Gemelli Logic 108 напольная colorglass белый глянец
 []
 Мебель для ванной Misty Орхидея 75 бежевый
 []

 Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Что `print(repr(name_picture))` печатает (нет ли пробелов в начале/конце, кодировка)? На Винде, лучше Юникодные имена файлов использовать. Присутствуют ли имена в `os.listdir(u'.')`? Не по теме: следует raw string literals использовать для путей в Windows, чтобы избежать сюрпризов: `r'c:\Users\temp'`

Comment: Спасибо разобрался, там действительно битый путь. Но как оказалось библиотека xlwt  несколько устарела и 2013 exel не может нормально отображать файлы, теперь познаю openpyxl......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Во первых замыленным глазом я не увидел банальной ошибки, я создавал новую книгу в теле цикла.

```
 workbook = xlwt.Workbook()
 worksheet = workbook.add_sheet('date')
```

Поэтому у меня всегда записывались последние найденные имена картинок. Недразумение с ссылкой я решил просто поменяв её на коренную. 
Честно говоря так и не понял в чем была настоящая причина, возможно в политике безопасности.
Что касается модуля openpyxl, то он упорно не хотел импортироваться, вернее даже не он, а workbook, хотя в питоновском интерпритаторе все было OK. Поэтому спустя некоторое время танцев с бубном, я решил сделать хитрее и сохранить все это дело в csv, нестандартным образом. Через:

```
 f.open('output.csv', w)
 f.write('sep=,')
 f.write('/n')
 f.write(current photos)
```

Надеюсь кому нибудь пригодиться.